# ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.XSLTMediator} - Unable to perform XSLT transformation

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to to do a sample provided in this [url](http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/04/integrate-rules-soa) , but i am getting error from xslt as:

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2013-02-25 13:08:55,280] 
ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.XSLTMediator} -  Unable to perform XSLT transformation using : Value {name ='null', keyValue ='conf:/repository/synapse/default/local-entries/CustomerOrderInputTransfer.xslt'} 
against source XPath : s11:Body/child::*[position()=1] | s12:Body/child::*[position()=1] {org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.XSLTMediator}

org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Error creating XSLT transformer using : Value {name ='null', keyValue ='conf:/repository/synapse/default/local-entries/CustomerOrderInputTransfer.xslt'}
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator.handleException(AbstractMediator.java:293)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.XSLTMediator.createTemplate(XSLTMediator.java:389)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.XSLTMediator.performXSLT(XSLTMediator.java:232)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.XSLTMediator.mediate(XSLTMediator.java:191)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:60)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:114)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingMethod(ServerWorker.java:416)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:268)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Cannot convert null to a StreamSource
    at org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfigUtils.handleException(SynapseConfigUtils.java:576)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfigUtils.getStreamSource(SynapseConfigUtils.java:77)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.XSLTMediator.createTemplate(XSLTMediator.java:379)
    ... 13 more
TID: [0] [ESB] [2013-02-25 13:08:55,282]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver} -  Exception encountered but no fault handler found - message dropped {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver}
```

I am clueless about how to rectify this bug. Plz help

Comment: before t his error i am getting a warning which is: WARN - SynapseConfigUtils Cannot convert null to a StreamSource

Comment: rttot log is not suffcient, please provide your XSLT file

Answer (score 1):

The WARN message that you get means that your xslt mediator is **not able to find** the file at the location 'conf:/repository/synapse/default/local-entries/CustomerOrderInputTransfer.xslt' .
If you are accessing it from local-entries folder, you can try specifying only `CustomerOrderInputTransfer.xslt` as the key attribute.

Comment: Still getting the same error. Not able to figure out why it is throwing this error

Comment: I had a look at the example, and it doesn't say where to put the example configuration files. Try to copy the 'CustemerOrderInputTransfer.xslt' into ./repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/local-entries/CustomerOrderInputTransfer.xslt